# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous - pulling out specific values in a dataframe

Tags: python, valueerror

I have a dataframe with different fruits e.g.

### FRUITS

1. apple,pear,blueberry
2. banana, pear
3. apple
4. apple,banana
5. blueberry, pear

I am trying to pull out only the rows with apples with this code:

[image]

but i keep getting the value error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: pandas works on all rows at once so you get result with many values `True`, `False` - use `print( df[ df['Fruits].... == True )` - and you get something like `if [True, False, True, ...]` and it doesn't know if it `True` or `False`. But all problem is that when you work with `iterrows` then you should use `if row['Fruits].... == True:`. OR you should use `print( df[ df['Fruits].... == True )` without `iterrows` and `if`

Answer (score 0):

`df` works on all rows at once so you get result with many values (many rows or many `True`, `False`) and you get something like `if [True, False, True, ...]:` and it doesn't know if it `True` or `False` - and it ask to use `all()`, `any()` to decide when it is `True`.

But real problem is that when you work with `iterrows` then you should use `row` instread of `df`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Fruits'].str.contains('apple'):
       print(row)
```

But it would be much simpler to do it without `iterrows`

```
print( df[ df['Fruits'].str.contains("apple") ] )
```